# Interpreting AUFS mounts

Tags: linux, filesystems, aufs

My question is the opposite of most on AUFS. I don't need to know how to mount two or more directories in a union.

Instead I need to understand what I am seeing on an existing system.

`/      aufs   aufs   rw,noatime,si=1725e3c381716971,noxino`

I have discovered the `findmnt -T path` will tell me which mount a directory belongs to but I don't see a way to tell which physical drives are being merged by the aufs I pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

It has taken more than a week of searching and synthesizing information and experimenting on my setup (a PC Engines apu running Debian 8 that I am attempting to boot and modify from a USB stick running TinyCore).

I have discovered that the aufs that I have encountered on the apu is composed of a squashfs.filesystem that contains a base image and is I believe mounted read only. It is then unioned with an overlay file that and I am still figuring out how that works. I'll update this with more details as I discover them.